# What permissions are required to use Linkedin Invitaitons API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to test Linkedin Invitations API and i can see that some permissions and approvals are require. Can you please let me what approvals/permissions are require for testing the API?

Answer (score 0):

This API falls under the Compliance Snapshot API, so you need the permissions listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/compliance-snapshot-overview?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-unversioned&preserve-view=true#permissions). However, know that access to the Compliance APIs is heavily restricted; see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/compliance-faq?view=li-lms-unversioned#how-can-i-get-access-to-the-compliance-apis-).